# When I make db process inside async map function, I can't avoid duplicate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await

I want to add pallet barcode to palletBarcodes field of record.But there is check for avoid add same palletBarcode.I am using below function. But check is not working inside async map function.

**myService.js**

```js
    const palletBarcodes = ["TP2","TP2"]
    await Promise.all(palletBarcodes.map(async (palletBarcode) => {
      const promise = await this.addPalletBarcode({ transferId, barcode: palletBarcode });
      return promise;
    }));

async addPalletBarcode({ transferId, barcode, pickerId }) {
    const { TransferDataAccess } = this;

    const transfer = await TransferDataAccess.getTransfer({ transferId });

    if (!transfer) {
      throw new TransferNotFoundError();
    }

    if (transfer.palletBarcodes.length && transfer.palletBarcodes.includes(barcode)) {
      throw new PalletBarcodeAlreadyExistsError({ barcode });
    }

    return TransferDataAccess.pushPalletBarcode({ transferId, barcode });
  }
```

**transferDataAccess:**

```
  async pushPalletBarcode({ transferId, barcode }) {
    const { TransferModel } = this;

    return TransferModel
      .findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: transferId,
      },
      {
        $push: {
          palletBarcodes: barcode,
        },
      })
      .lean()
      .exec();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$push` use `$addToSet`. `$addToSet` will treat your key in document as a set and that will automatically avoid duplicates.

You query would then become -

```
TransferModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  { _id: transferId },
  { $addToSet: { palletBarcodes: barcode } }
);
```